# JavaScript help running a basic function on button click

Tags: javascript, forms, function, button

Just trying to run a simple function when the button "calculate" is pressed. Function won't run at all when inputs are in a form, ultimately I want to be able to modify the other inputs when the calculate button is pressed. Any help at all please!

```js
function calculate() {
  alert("called");
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<form name="form">
  Price:
  <input name="priceCAD" value="0">
  <br>
  <br>Markup:
  <input name="percentage" value="0">
  <br>
  <br>Fiat:
  <input name="fiat" value="0">
  <br>
  <br>BTC:
  <input name="btc" value="0" maxlength="11">
  <br>
  <br>

  <input type="button" onClick="calculate()" name="calculate" value="Caculate">
  <input type="button" name="clear" value="Clear" onClick="form.fiat.value=0, form.btc.value=0, form.markup.value=0">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button HTML just need it:

```
<input type="button" onClick="calculate()" name="calculate" value="Caculate" >
```

And don't forget insert `jquery lib` in your `<head>`.

Comment: I left document.calculate by accident in there. Where do I insert jquery lib? In all the examples i've been going off of online I have not seen that once.

Comment: Between `<html>` and `<body>`. Like this: <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

Comment: Made the changes and still nothing. If I get rid of the form tags it calls on the function no problem. However with the 2 form tags in it doesn't get to the function.

Comment: Try change       `<input type="button" onclick="calculates();" name="calculate" value="Caculate" />` and js is `function calculates() {
            alert("called");
        }`

Comment: Look like have conflict at function `javascript name` and `input name`.

Comment: Yes that was the issue thanks! Can't have a function name and element name the same.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calculate() {
  alert("called");
}

document.getElementsByName("calculate")[0].addEventListener("click", calculate);
```

```html
<form name="form">
  Price:
  <input name="priceCAD" value="0">
  <br>
  <br>Markup:
  <input name="percentage" value="0">
  <br>
  <br>Fiat:
  <input name="fiat" value="0">
  <br>
  <br>BTC:
  <input name="btc" value="0" maxlength="11">
  <br>
  <br>

  <input type="button" name="calculate" value="Caculate">
  <input type="button" name="clear" value="Clear" onClick="form.fiat.value=0, form.btc.value=0, form.markup.value=0">
</form>
```